# How to configure WebStorm to recognize node in an existing project, error: unresolved function require

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I have an existing project that I've opened in WebStorm and it's not recognizing node.js globals.  I saw a post saying go to preferences and add Node.js globals to the libraries but I don't see that in my latest WebStorm 11.  Looking at another project that does work (created by using the new node.js app command in WebStorm), I don't see the node.js globals in its library preferences- so I'm not sure if that is the solution.

It works fine if I create a new project through WebStorm specifying a node.js project, but how do I configure an existing project?

Answer (score 0):

Found the asnwer -> Preferences - Languages & Frameworks - Node.js and NPM - enable Code Assistance: Node Core library.