# Coding Assistance or Type Hints in WebStorm for event handlers

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, type-hinting

I'm sure this is a frequently asked question, but I couldn't find an answer searching on my own.

I'm learning Node using WebStorm as my IDE.  I have enabled Coding Assistance as described at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34251938/how-to-configure-webstorm-to-recognize-node-in-an-existing-project-error-unres).

And it starts to work:

[image]

Now further down as I start hooking up event handlers for my objects. In this case, a simple event handler for an incoming connection on a `net.Server` object. But it has no idea about the type of the object expected by the callback function passed to `server.on`.  So as soon as I type `.` to bring up the coding assistance dialog for `clientSocket`, it can only show me the common methods for `Object`, and not the `net.Socket` type that the object is really expected to be.

[image]

I get that JavaScript is weakly typed and that it would be a challenge for any IDE to auto identify the type of such variables as the developer is typing.

If there is a way WebStorm could be configured to do that, then great.  Otherwise, is there some simple annotation or comment I could add to the code such that the IDE is given a hint as to a variables actual object type such that coding assistance would work in this case?

Comment: You can explicit tell your ide what type of variable your parameter is. by using `/** @param TYPE name */` above your function declaration. If your ide knows this declaration, it can provide you an autocomplete.

Comment: I tried different variations of that.  It did not appear to work.  Maybe you could be persuaded to write out a full answer showing how to annotate an event handler passed to `on` ?

Comment: I do not know what type `clientSocket` actually is since i have never written applications for Node.js. I can only answer in a more general way (for example for a simple load event):
`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',
    /**
    * @param {Event} param
    */
    function(param) {}
);`
Note the `{}` inside the comment. I guess the only thing that is missing, is the correct type of the parameter of node.js EventListener callbacks.

Comment: Woot.  It works now if I inline the comment exactly as you have. And finally, changing the type hint from `net.Socket` to just `Socket` and it works.  Thanks!

Comment: Sort of works... it only shows a limited set of members, but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bottom line.  WebStorm just doesn't do intellisense very well with a language such as JavaScript that isn't strongly typed.

I switched to VS Code and set it up for TypeScript and it just works.  Then I tried out Visual Studio 2017 with its node support. Wow - everything works with Typescript out of the box.

Comment: 2018 update. I did eventually get an update to WebStorm going and got this mostly working *with TypeScript* using the steps I outlined [for this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48856573/104458)